# Apache Maven Plugin copy video wrong in JavaFX, Maven, NetBeans project

Tags: maven, netbeans, javafx, javafx-8

a) Given is a JavaFX 8, Maven, NetBeans project.
b) In pom.xml I define

```
<resources>
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
      <include>**/*.css</include>
      <include>**/*.png</include>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
      <include>**/*.mp4</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

c) During the **'Clean and Build'** task my videos will be copied to the **'target'** folder (and also in the jar).

d) After copy the videos increase in large from ~1MB to ~1.6MB.
e) Navigating to the **'videos'** in the 'target' folder or unzip the jar shows that the videos are also corrupted. They can't play anymore with the **'Windows Media Player'**.

So my question is "How can I avoid that during the copy the videos going corrupted"?

Comment: Try with filtering:false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like 'alpert' said, disable the tag filtering=false works.

Because I need für my .properties files filtering=true I found the solution on the side from the [Apache Maven Resource Plugn - Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) -> binary resources shouldn't filtered because they will be corrupted.

The advice from the side is to have 2 resource folders, one with resources which will be filtered (.css, .properties) and another folder with resource which won't be filtered (.png, .mp4).

One more possibility is to use [Binary filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    ...
    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      <nonFilteredFileExtension>mp4</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```